# Drupal 7: Flags for a single forum and indexed search covering all forums

Tags: php, drupal-7, forum, flags

I'm using the Drupal 7 core Forum with Advanced Forum on top for my website.  One of the forums is for support requests with a similar functionality to stackoverflow.com.  But unlike Stack Overflow a user only has the ability to set the entire thread as "Solved", not a single post.  Right now this is realized via a flag and me checking for the id of the support forum via a hook, displaying the link and message accordingly, which feels more like a workaround than an actual solution.

Also, when searching through multiple forums using the Search API module, if a user has either selected "Solved" or "Unsolved" (instead of "Any") there won't be any results from other forums beside the one for support, because they do not have the flag set.  It should only really count for the forum that actually allows the flag to be set, though, while all others should simply be searched for keywords.

Is there any better way to go about this?  I already searched for modules of this kind, which was pretty unsuccessful.  If anyone has any past experience about similar problems, help would be very much appreciated.

**Edit:**
When creating a flag for the status "Solved" / "Unsolved", this flag appears for the main thread of every forum I create, not just the Support Forum. But none of the other forums are supposed to have the option to set it. Right now I am using a custom template for the thread view and read the tid from the forum's breadcrumbs to check whether I am in the correct forum to display the flag. But is there a better / correct way to do it? Is there a way to tell the flag to only appear in the Support Forum without using the breadcrumbs?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you programming your message with custom code? Did you have a look at flags rules integration? You can then load the flagged content and display a message

Regarding the search: Unflagged content is not flagged by definition. Neither solved or unsolved, it is just null or to be clear: related to a flag filter. I am not sure how to implement it with search API but with views itself you simply could add the relation to flagged content (not required) and filter where the user that flagged the content is empty (null).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but there was a bit of a misunderstanding with the one who translated this question for me. I edited my question with what I actually wanted to know."